PHP 8 how to concisely increment dynamically generated variables
PHP 8 raised the Notice to a Warning that an unset variable/array key is worked on.
PHP 7.4:
// Below would create a variable and set it to 0 + 1
// Below would generate a Notice level error.
$_SESSION['dynamic']['var']++;

PHP 8+:
// Below would create a variable and set it to 0 + 1
// Below would create a warning level error that variable does not exist. 
$_SESSION['dynamic']['var']++;

Question:
With a dynamically generated variable (in the broadest sense; a variable or an array element value) such as a $_SESSION key value, how can we maintain the current action but prevent the Warning being issued. Hopefully without needing to add loads of extra code bloat.
The only way I can think of is
$_SESSION['dynamic']['var'] = ($_SESSION['dynamic']['var']??0)+1; 

Which is a pretty big bloat of code from ++ to ($var??0)+1.
This seems to entirely negate the whole shortcut of ++ and -- convenient increment/decrement operators. There is no mention of this on the PHP manual pages.

I don't think the shortcut is supposed to be used on not existing/dynamic variables.

@CornelRaiu since PHP 4 it's been an established routine to increment on a baseline that if a var doesn't exist it can be made to exist and incremented to 1.

"There is no mention of this on the PHP manual pages." - the behavior is not specific to these particular operators. $foo + 3 will also result in a warning (resp. a Notice, previously) and a value of 3, if $foo is not defined. "how can we maintain the current action but prevent the Warning being issued" - if you consider proper initialization to be "code bloat", then only by suppressing all warnings, I suppose.

Your question consistently uses the word "variable", but the examples are all of an undefined array key, except for the one at the very end of ($var??0)+1. While they give similar warnings, these are actually different scenarios, and may have different solutions (although I don't think there are any at the moment).

Generally speaking, reading an undefined variable was promoted from notice to warning (online demo). See "A number of notices have been converted into warnings" in the migration guide. IMHO, notices are a developer tool and coding in 7.x without the aid of notices was a bit of a loss.

@Martin I agree that it's the way PHP used to be written. I was there and wrote PHP since v3.0.4. However, also having knowledge and experience in compiled languages, incrementing an undefined array key/variable would never compile so I was never on the same boat with this established routine. As mentioned by @CBroe , if incrementing a possible undefined var/array key will pass as ok code for you, you can just the @ and suppress the respective warning or use the nullish coalescing operator (??) to initialize the variable before the increment but that would no longer be a one-liner.

@IMSoP my main issue is using keys of the Session variable array. Yes, I should technically update my question. Done. But I would like to resolve this language wide rather than for a specific type of variable . If you can answer either / or of these (variable or array element) that would be good.

In PHP 8, you can use the null coalescing operator (??) along with the nullsafe operator (?->) to concisely auto-increment dynamically generated variables within an array. This allows you to handle unset variables gracefully without raising warnings.
 $_SESSION['dynamic']['var'] ??= 0;
 $_SESSION['dynamic']['var']++;


I was curious of there was any sort of shorter version to achieve this. Thanks.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

If you don't mind using a reference, you can initialize or modify the value by using another variable with a shorter name.
$v = &$_SESSION['dynamic']['var'];
$v++;
$v = &$_SESSION['dynamic2']['var2']; 
$v += 10;
unset($v);

print_r($_SESSION);
/*
Array
(
    [dynamic] => Array
        (
            [var] => 1
        )

    [dynamic2] => Array
        (
            [var2] => 10
        )

)
*/


What does the reference achieve here?

Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

@Martin if you run the code, $_SESSION['dynamic']['var'] will be set to 1, $_SESSION['dynamic2']['var2'] will be set to 10, and no warnings.

Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

You can suppress the warning using @ prefix like this:
@$_SESSION['dynamic']['var']++;

But relying on default value of undefined variable/index is not exactly a good practice. It might be better to go with longer version you've suggested yourself.

Suppressing warnings (especially, Warnings) is not a good practise.
